# Recommendations for Form Integrations with Salesforce?

Tags: form, plugin-sproutforms

I'm new to Craft and really loving it so far. I'd like to use something like Sprout Forms or Freeform (are there others worth looking at?) but I really need to be able to submit any data to Salesforce.

I know Freeform has a Salesforce integration but from talking with support it sounds like it only works with Leads and I need custom Object support.

i.e. we have job application forms and other applications that use custom Objects and from time to time we do add others.

With Sprout Forms I've been looking into [Payload Forwarding](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms/docs/customization/payload-forwarding) and what I could maybe do with that.

Does anyone have any experience with this and any recommended approaches? I'm more of a Front-End Dev so looking at something I could sort myself but if not I'll be looking at hiring someone to help me pull a solution together.

Answer (score 1):

Sprout Forms it's a good option for your requirements, using the Payload Forwarding you'll be able to send the data to an endpoint on salesforce, you can also use the Hidden Field or the Invisible Field from the [Sprout Fields](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/fields) plugin to setup any pre-filled API-keys if required.